# Filtering list of objects in datagridview based on cell value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, reflection

I am currently unsure on the best way of going about getting a filter to work right on a datagridview that has its datasource set to a list of objects.

So given an object of:

```
    public class DepositAccountBill
    {
        #region Properties
        public int AccountBillID { get; set; }
        public int AccountID { get; set; }
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string ControlNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime BillDate { get; set; }
        public decimal DepositAmount { get; set; }
}
```

I have a datagridview table that looks roughly like this:

```
Account Number  |  Control Number  | Bill Date  |   Deposit Amount 
==================================================================
123456          | AJA1234367       | 5/21/2018  | 12.99 
123456          | PSA1234367       | 5/21/2018  | 5.77 
567332          | HBA1234367       | 5/21/2018  | 1255.99 
769843          | AJA1234367       | 5/21/2018  | 12.99
```

So when clicking on a cell. Lets say the first cell on the first column. If I right click a cell and select an option in a context Menu that says filter I need to display the datagridview table with only rows that have the same Account number. In this case, it would be rows 1 and 2.
In order for me to do this, I have to access the object that the datagridview table is populated with DepositAccountBill.  So what I need to do is look and at the column I'm looking at has the selected cell's value.

So in my method I have tried thus far with no results:

```
var collection = (List<DepositAccountBill>)dataGridView1.DataSource;
var filterList = collection.Where ( q => (collection.Select(r => GetPropValue(r, dataGridView1.Columns[clickedCell.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName))) == (clickedCell.Value);

dataGridView1.DataSource = filterList.ToList();

public object GetPropValue(object obj, string propName)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

I don't know if SELECT is the right LINQ method to use here or if this is even possible.
I want to use WHERE because it only grabs the list of objects that match the condition. Something like this:

```
var filterList = collection.Where(r => r.AccountNumber == clickedCell.Value);
```

Only problem is the `r.AccountNumber` is dependant on the data property of the selected column. The program does not know what the data property is based on a click event on the selected cell. This is why I think reflection might be necessary.

Comment: In what event are you handeling the code above?

Comment: I am handling the event from a right click event (CellMouseUp) on the selected cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you know how to extract the property name using `DataPropertyName` property of the column and also how to get the value from `Value` property of the cell.

In the answer I'll focus on how to perform dynamic filtering a *`List<T>`* having *Property Name* and the *Value*, like when you use `.Where(x=>x.PropertyName == Value)`.

To do so, you have a couple of options which you can choose, including:

1. Dynamic Linq Library
2. Creating `Expression` dynamically at run-time
3. Using a `Dictionary` containing criteria that you need for each property
4. Simply using if/else

I'll share more details about above solutions and you can choose either of them.

---

**Note:** *If the answer is too long, probably the easiest and most obvious answer would be 4th option.*

---

### Option 1 - Dynamic Linq Library

As an option you can add `System.Linq.Dynamic` reference to your project, then after using `System.Linq.Dynamic` namespace, you will be able to create dynamic queries on `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` by passing criteria as `string`, for example:

```
var list = db.Products.ToList();
var result = list.Where("Name = @0", "product1").ToList();
```

This way you can simply use the column data property name and column value in the query dynamically. To find more about dynamic linq, take a look at following resources:

- [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) for `System.Linq.Dynamic`. You can install the package simply using this command in package manager console: `Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic`
- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) for `System.Linq.Dynamic`
- [Scott Guthrie's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)
  about *Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)*

### Option 2 - Create Lambda Expression at run-time

As another option you can create lambda expression at run-time and use it with `Where` method.  For example, you can create the following method:

```
//Creates x=>x.Something == value
public Expression<Func<T, bool>> EqualCriteria<T>(string propertyName, object value)
{
    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(x, property.Name);
    var valueExpression = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value),
        property.PropertyType);
    var criteria = Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, valueExpression);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(criteria, x);
    return lambda;
}
```

And then use it this way:

```
var list = db.Products.ToList();
var result = list.Where(EqualCriteria<Product>("Name", "product1").Compile()).ToList();
```

As you can see, also in this solution, you can use column data property name and value dynamically.

### Option 3 - Using predefined criteria in a dictionary

As another option you can create a dictionary containing the criteria which you need, then use them dynamically. For example let's say you've created the following dictionary:

```
var criterias = new Dictionary<string, Func<Product, object, bool>>() {
    { "Id" , (p,v)=>p.Id.Equals(v) },
    { "Name" , (p,v)=>p.Name.Equals(v) }
};
```

Then based on the column data property name and cell value, you can simply use the following statement to filter the list:

```
var list = db.Products.ToList();
var result = list.Where(x => criterias["Name"](x, "product1")).ToList();
```

### Option 4 - Using if/else

As another option you can use if/else conditions simply. For example let's say you've the value in an object variable and property name in a string variable, then you can write:

```
var list = db.Products.ToList();
var result = list.ToList();
if (propertyName == "Id")
{
    result = result.Where(x=>x.Id == (int)value).ToList();
}
else if (propertyName == "Name")
{
    result = result.Where(x=>x.Name == (string)value).ToList();
}
```