# How to ensure case insensitive comparison on strings when comparing unknown object types?

Tags: c#, .net, string, object, comparison

I have a DataGridView that I am writing some generic code to add filters to. The underlying data types for the columns could be anything, however if they are strings I would like the filter to use a case insensitive comparison.

I also am using the `Equals` method rather than the `==` operator to make sure it's not just doing a reference comparison. The string `Equals` method has an overload to let you choose a `StringComparison` type, but I don't know whether it's going to be a string or not so I only have access to the `Equals` method available to an `object`.

I tried writing an `Equals` extension method for `object` that would let me specify a `StringComparison` type. The idea being that if the objects were strings then it would call the appropriate `Equals` overload on the string object, but otherwise it would just use the normal `Equals` method. However this does not seem to work as I get a compile error stating that I can't access the method as an instance method and must specify a type. I've included the extension method below in case I've done something wrong in it... I did write it hastily but I don't think it's the problem; I think I just have to find another way to do it.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Equals(this object obj1, object obj2, StringComparison comparisonType)
    {
        if (obj1 == null && obj2 == null)
            return true;
        if (obj1 == null && obj2 != null)
            return false;
        if (obj1 != null && obj2 == null)
            return false;

        string s = obj1 as string;

        if (s != null)
        {
            var s2 = obj2 as string;
            return s2 != null && s.Equals(s2, comparisonType);
        }
        else
            return obj1.Equals(obj2);
    }
}
```

So I'm looking for either a better approach or if I simply made a mistake in the above code please let me know.

EDIT:

Also below is what consuming code looks like. _filters is just a list of objects with a few properties such as you see referenced below and items is `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
        foreach (var f in _filters)
        {
            items = items.Where(o => o[f.FieldName].Equals(f.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        }
```

Comment: Yes the extension method compiles fine. Its the code in the EDIT I just added that doesn't compile.

Comment: Use another extension method like `IsEqual`, inside the method check if the parameter is string, compare in your preferred way.

Comment: @RezaAghaei That did it. Feel dumb for not thinking of it myself. Thanks!

Comment: Most if this method is redundant

Comment: _"I also am using the `Equals` method rather than the `== `operator to make sure it's not just doing a reference comparison"_ Well, unless `Equals` is overridden with some comparison logic, it will still do reference comparison for reference objects.

Comment: You could achieve most of it with `string.Equals(obj1 as string, obj2 as string, comparisonType);`

Comment: @MichaelRandall The point is to have a succinct method I can call from a lambda method. I don't know if it's a string or not so I have to make the comparison support all types, but I want to factor out that logic into an extension method .

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yes, and honestly it's probably not even necessary for what I'm doing now. but I have had to use it in the past and, more importantly, the compiler was giving me a warning about it that I wanted to shut up. But I knew someone like you would make a comment about it so that's why I purposefully pointed it out so hopefully you'd realize I knew what I was doing. Guess it didn't work though, lol. ;)

Comment: @MichaelRandall Sure, but it took me less time to write this way, it's simple, and it performs just as well as the perfect one you would have written for any purpose I will be using it for. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another extension method like `IsEqual`, then inside the method check if the parameter is string, compare in your preferred way.

For example, something like the following code. I haven't tested the functionality, it's just demonstrating the idea:

```
public static class ObjectExtesions
{
    public static bool IsEqual(this object left, object right)
    {
        if (left == null && right == null)
            return true;
        if (left != null && right != null)
        {
            if (left is string && right is string)
                return ((string)left).Equals((string)right,
                    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            else
                return left.Equals(right);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar while the code is just an example to demonstrate the idea, but to answer your question, yes we need to do null checking because of `left.Equals(right)` → It will throw exception if left is null string.

Comment: What to make it easier or more elegant? take a look at this post to get some idea using dynamic linq or dynamic lambda expression: [Filtering list of objects in datagridview based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50479387/3110834)

Comment: Don't miss the linked post. It's a bit long but it most likely will help. You just need consider option 1 and option 2.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have some custom rolled code I wrote a long time ago that helps a ton with this. It uses some reflection to work with the properties and I have a list that supports filtering and sorting but I just wanted to update the filter comparison to support this.

Comment: Cool! you know your requirements better. Just wanted to share something which may help :)

Comment: Definitely! I'm actually am appreciative of your tip even though in retrospect I realize it sounds like I was saying I already got my bases covered and didn't need it, lol. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The string comparison bit can be much simpler by using the static string Equals method:

```
return string.Equals(obj1.ToString(), obj2.ToString(), comparisonType);
```

1. You've already null checked obj1 and obj2
2. Casting obj1 as string isn't actually converting it into a string, it just means the compiler is letting you use string-like methods on it.

Edit: for clarity, this would be my full static method:

```
public static class ObjectHelper
{
    public static bool EqualStrings(object obj1, object obj2, StringComparison comparisonType)
    {
        return string.Equals(obj1?.ToString(), obj2?.ToString(), comparisonType);
    }
}
```

I personally wouldn't have an extension method on object - it's going to pollute your intellisense. And I would use null check operators for brevity.

Comment: It will only pollute where I have the related namespace in the using section. And how does this solution handle scenarios where the object is not a string? If I knew it was a string then as you said I wouldn't even bother with an extension method. But I need it to behave appropriately whether it's a string or some other data type.

Comment: Also "polluting" totally doesn't bother me. I'm more about getting work done than about making sure my workshop is clean if you know what I mean.

Comment: The .ToString() method is what makes it a string. If you are using custom objects you can override the ToString method that comes with all objects to provide whatever string should represent that class.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get from your question that you want to use string comparison for strings, otherwise fallback to object equality.